# What's the correct way of handling web requests during database maintenance?

Tags: database, http, web, webserver, http-error

Scenario: You are going to do scheduled database maintenance. You will hence be unable to serve dynamic content (just assume the caching system in front of the database also needs to be maintained).

**During that time, what's the correct way of handling web requests trying to access a dynamic resource?**

What's the correct HTTP error code, if any, that goes along with the notice that your service is currently not available? Should you use errors in the *5XX* range?

What are the implications in terms of SEO? Will it hurt if search engine crawlers try to access your site  and see lots of error codes or pages with the same notice instead of dynamic content? Can you easily recover from that?

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1):

503 Service Unavailable is the correct response to use in this situation.

Comment: What about the SEO aspect, when you're unlucky enough to have a search engine crawler crawl your pages right at the moment of database maintenance?

Comment: The crawler can tell, from the 503 code, that the response it received is not the page that it asked for.  Based on that, it should know to leave its search index untouched for now, and to try again later.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your site works, you could just put up a static HTML page replacing everything saying that the site is undergoing maintenance.